# OpenIdDict did not return redirectUrl , "System.InvalidOperationException: A sign-in response cannot be returned from this endpoint."

Tags: .net-core, openiddict

I'm facing the weird issues with OpenIddict. I am trying to replace IdentityServer with OpenIddict, everything worked fine as expected.

I followed [this](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Balosar/Balosar.Server/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs)

I write localhost client test and it connected to server without any problem on localhost.

This is my OpenIddict setup:

- .NET 8.0
- OpenIddict 4.10.1

```cs
public static void AddConsioAuthenticationDict(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

    // Enable Quartz.NET integration.
    services.AddQuartz(options =>
    {
        options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
        options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
        options.UseInMemoryStore();
    });

    X509Certificate2? privateKey = null;
    string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(currentDirectory + "\\secretCert.pfx");
    if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 2)
    {
        privateKey = new X509Certificate2(bytes, "somepassword");
    }

    if (privateKey == null)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        for (int i = 0; i < store.Certificates.Count; i++)
        {
            X509Certificate2? cert = store.Certificates[i];
            var serial = configuration["NetsSoapSetting:certificate-serial"];
            var thumbprint = configuration["NetsSoapSetting:certificate-thumbprint"];

            if (string.Equals(cert.SerialNumber, serial, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                string.Equals(cert.Thumbprint, thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                privateKey = cert;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
        // Note: use the generic overload if you need to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
        options.UseOpenIddict();
    });
    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

    services.AddOpenIddict()
        .AddCore(option =>
        {
            option.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
            option.UseQuartz();
        })
        .AddServer(option =>
        {
            option.RegisterScopes(
                OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Profile);
            option.RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange();

            option.Configure(options => options.CodeChallengeMethods.Add(OidcConstants.CodeChallengeMethods.Plain));
            option.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize/");
            // Enable the token endpoint.8
            option.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token/");

            // Enable the client credentials flow.
            option.SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo/");
            option.SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout/");

            option.AllowImplicitFlow();
            option.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();
            option.AllowPasswordFlow();
            option.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow().RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange(); ;
            option.AllowHybridFlow();
            option.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

            option
                .AddSigningCertificate(privateKey);
            //option.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
            //    .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

            // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core options.
            option.UseAspNetCore()
                .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough();
            option
                .AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
                .AddEphemeralSigningKey();
            // encrypt the access token to hide all info public!
            //.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();
        })
        .AddValidation(options =>
        {
            // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
            options.UseLocalServer();
            options.EnableTokenEntryValidation();
            // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
            options.UseAspNetCore();
        });
}
```

And this is my `Authorize` method:

```cs
[HttpGet("~/connect/authorize")]
[HttpPost("~/connect/authorize")]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize()
{
    //var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
    //              throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");
    var remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    //var GrantTypes = request.GrantType;
    //var clientSecret = request.ClientSecret;
    // Retrieve the user principal stored in the authentication cookie.
    //var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

    // If the user principal can't be extracted, redirect the user to the login page.
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Challenge(
            authenticationSchemes: IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            properties: new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Request.PathBase + Request.Path + QueryString.Create(
                    Request.HasFormContentType ? Request.Form.ToList() : Request.Query.ToList())
            });
    }

    var userId = string.Empty;

    if (HttpContext.User.Identity != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name))
    {
        var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

        if (user != null)
        {
            userId = user.Id;
        }
    }

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        // 'subject' claim which is required
        new Claim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject, userId),
        new Claim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.ExpiresAt, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1).ToString()),
        new Claim("someclaim", "somevalue").SetDestinations(OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken),
        new Claim("originalIp", remoteIpAddress.ToString()).SetDestinations(OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken),
    };

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
    // Set requested scopes (this is not done automatically)
    //claimsPrincipal.SetScopes(request.GetScopes());

    // Signing in with the OpenIddict authentication scheme trigger OpenIddict to issue a code (which can be exchanged for an access token)
    // Create a new authentication ticket for the user's principal
    return SignIn(claimsPrincipal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

I got two big issues:

- `GetOpenIddictServerRequest()` is always null on IIS server, so If I take this out

  ```
  return SignIn(claimsPrincipal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) will krasj
  ```

  then I got this:

  > System.InvalidOperationException: A sign-in response cannot be returned from this endpoint.

I need to understand why `GetOpenIddictServerRequest();` worked only on localhost, and redirectUrl could not return?

Answer (score 2):

Finally! I find out what happend! "connect/authorize" is set up in "AddOpenIddict" like this:

```
     option.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("connect/authorize");
```

but in my **controller** :

```
    [HttpGet("~/connect/authorize")]
    [HttpPost("~/connect/authorize")]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize()
```

So this is not correct path in MVC! I set "connect" at the root of my controller
and

```
[Route("connect")]
public class AuthorizationController : Controller
```

and set each enpoint like this:

```
 [HttpGet("authorize")]
 [HttpPost("authorize")]
 [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize()
```

and it worked!